# Undefine reference to... : inheritance from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have some trouble with inheritance from a template class. The code below does not compile, showing this error : `main.cpp : undefined reference to OBJ1<1000>::method()`

**parent.h**

```
template <int nb>
class PARENT
{
  PARENT() {};
  ~PARENT() {};

  virtual void method() = 0;
  enum { nb_ = nb };
};
```

**obj1.h**

```
#include "parent.h"

template <int nb>
class OBJ1 : public PARENT<nb>
{
  virtual void method();
};
```

**obj1.cpp**

```
#include "obj1.h"

template <int nb>
void OBJ1<nb>::method()
{
  //code
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "obj1.h"

int main()
{
  OBJ1<1000> toto;
  toto.method();
}
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with templates you cannot split declaration and implementation into separate files. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1025391) for the reasons (and also for a more concise description to workaround this).

This needs to be merged (You can also `#include` the implementation file into the header to let the preprocessor do the merge.):

```
// obj1.hpp

#include "parent.h"

template <int nb>
class OBJ1 : public PARENT<nb>
{
  virtual void method();
};

template <int nb>
void OBJ1<nb>::method()
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: The code still can't compile, but you fixed one mistake. :) Thanks.

Comment: When you define a method for a class template out of line as was done here, it's best to mark that out of line definition as `inline`. Without that `inline`, a violation of the one definition rule will result if multiple source files use that function for the same template arguments.

Comment: @DavidHammen isn't there an exception for templates? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3694899/1025391

Comment: No exception. It's the same as for a (non-template) class. If you define the function inside the class, the function is inline by default. There's no need for the `inline` keyword for functions defined in line because it's already inline. By default. You separated the definition from the declaration. The same rules apply as for a class: If you don't qualify an out of line definition with the `inline` keyword, the function isn't an `inline` function. In C++, the primary purpose of `inline` is with regard to the one definition rule. That the function *might* be inlined; that's just a hint.