# Optional header only library

Tags: c++, header-files, libraries, organization, header-only

I'd like to write a C++ library which is *not-header-only* by default but could be used as a header only library defining a `NOLIB` macro.

I've seen two approaches:

- **inline definitions**

*foo.h*

```
#if !defined(FOO_H)
#define      FOO_H

#if defined(NOLIB)
#  define MYINLINE inline
#else 
#  define MYINLINE 
#endif

class foo
{
  // ...
};

#if defined(NOLIB)
#  include "foo.cc"
#endif

#endif  // include guard
```

*foo.cc*

```
#if !defined(NOLIB)
#  include "foo.h"
#endif

MYINLINE void foo::something() { ... }
```

---

- **"Artificial" template**

*foo.h*

```
#if !defined(FOO_H)
#define      FOO_H

#if defined(NOLIB)
#  define MYTEMPLATE template<bool DUMMY>
#  define MYFOO      foo_impl
#  define MYFOO_T    foo_impl<DUMMY>
#else
#  define MYTEMPLATE
#  define MYFOO      foo
#  define MYFOO_T    foo
#endif

MYTEMPLATE
class MYFOO
{
  // ...
};

#if defined(NOLIB)
   using foo = foo_impl<true>;
#  include "foo.cc"
#endif

#endif  // include guard
```

*foo.cc*

```
#if !defined(NOLIB)
#  include "foo.h"
#endif

MYTEMPLATE
void MYFOO_T::something() { ... }
```

What are the pros and cons of these approaches? Are there better options?

Comment: If the functions are small enough to be inlined, you could potentially ship the implementations in a static library, or even ship the .cc files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference in each approach because both inline methods or templates could end up be inserted inline with your code depending on compiler optimizations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694923/3571171) post discussing inline vs templates.

Comment: I‘m not too worried of code bloat one reason being that header-only version would be for casual user. I was thinking of problems like circular dependency or other unforeseen issues that may emerge trying to convert a standard library. Also the artificial template seems a stretch of C++ language.

Comment: I think the main thing to watch for in either case is to avoid having a using namespace line in your code which could cause problems for the end user, so you should implement everything within a namespace (if you are suing them). You could have circular dependencies in either of the cases you mentioned.